# Restrict user from installing application on device

Tags: android

Hello as i have to restrict user from installing the application on more than one device, i.e if the user have installed the application on one device that application should not get installed on another device.
Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please be a bit more informative. What do you exactly want, do you want to check whether a particular email id has already downloaded the app from the Google Play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is to save the IMEI (serial) of the Mobile on a certain server and authenticate this IMEI every time the Application is used. You have to limit access to the IMEIs on the server (authorized users). You can read the IMEI using `android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()` (you have to ask for permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />`)